# Passing Database object to subclassed QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Not sure why I can't get past this one but I am attempting to subclass QSQLTableModel and I have to pass the database to it...but I am not exactly sure how.

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(SclDataModel, self).__init__(parent)

class SclDataBrowse(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setup_db()
        self.setup_model()

    def setup_db(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase("QMYSQL")
        self.db.setHostName("myhost")
        self.db.setUserName("myuser")
        self.db.setPassword("mypassword")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("mydbname")
        self.db.open()

    def setup_model(self):
        self.model = SclDataModel(self,self.db)
```

Could use a little push here.  Thanks.

Comment: Still working through this one.  I'm certain is it spot on, though.

Comment: What do you doubt? If you have any questions, you should give a feedback

Comment: No doubts.  I just like to understand the code rather than cut and paste. So I am studying your answer. You haven't let me down yet though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions:

- If you do not want to do anything in the constructor then do not overwrite it and therefore the child class will use the same construct of the parent class

You can use `pass` if you're not going to overwrite anything:

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    pass
```

Or if you are going to implement some other method it is not necessary to `pass`

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def other_method(self, some_args):
        # some code
```

- If you want to do something in the constructor one option is to use the [same constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#QSqlTableModel) as the parent class

---

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, db=QSqlDatabase()):
        super(SclDataModel, self).__init__(parent, db)
        # other code
```

- If you do not want to worry about using `*args` and `**kwargs`

---

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SclDataModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # other code
```

Understand that inheritance is used to customize a class, so for example the constructor of the inherited class could not match the constructor of the parent class, for example:

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2=v_default,parent=None, db=QSqlDatabase()):
        super(SclDataModel, self).__init__(parent, db)
        self._arg1 = arg1
        self._arg2 = arg2
        # other code
```

In conclusion the parameters of the constructor will depend on your needs